# Importing .java and .class file gone wrong in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file

Recently I worked on a project on a mac, using eclipse. When I was done with the project I copied certain .java files and their corresponding .class files onto a USB drive and brought it to my personal computer. When I try to use the import feature on eclipse and import everything, my main method is not recognized by eclipse. It will work if I create a new eclipse "class" by the name I have in the program and copy paste the code. I have many classes so I can not do this for each one. Is there any way for me to change all .java/.class files into files that will be read by the system?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An eclipse project contains a lot of meta information. Just open the project directory in a file browser, and have a closer look. There are files like .classpath for example.

When you just copy your source code, you leave all the meta information behind!

You should either copy the complete project directory, or simply use the export task to create a ZIP file of your project. (to later import that in other systems).

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way you can do this. Just create a new project with the SAME EXACT PROJECT NAME that you did at school or wherever. After you create your project, go to your file explorer and navigate to the following place:

<"Directory to work-space">/<"Project Name">/src/

For ex: in Windows, it is Generally:
C:/Users/your_name/workspace/projectName/src

In here, copy all your ".java" files.

Now go to eclipse, right click on your project and hit refresh. You will find all your .java files there. Right-click on your project and hit "Run"->"Run as a Java Project". It should run! hope this helps.

PS: You do not need your class if you are executing it in Eclipse. Eclipse will create its own class files.